# Is the UIDatePicker really the best iPhone UI mechanism for selecting dates?

Tags: iphone, uikit, ipad, calendar

I'm diving into iPhone/iPad development and I'm trying to find an elegant mechanism for allowing the user to select dates.  It seems to me that a calendar control would be the best way to go, but I don't see one in anywhere in the SDK.  All all I see is this overblown, the-price-is-right-looking DatePicker control.

1. Is this the only control that comes with UIKit for allowing the user to select dates?
2. What about the calendar control that the Calendar app uses?

Also, I should note I'm really trying to avoid using 3rd party code frameworks that have little or no documentation, because I'm new to all this and sufficient documentation on how to use it is a must at this point.  Thanks so much in advance for all your wisdom!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this the only control that comes with UIKit for allowing the user to select dates?

Yes

> What about the calendar that the Notes app uses?

(Do you mean the Calendar app? I don't recall any date pickers in Notes app.)

It's in the private CalendarUI.framework. There exists 3rd-party libraries, and you could implement one yourself, of course.